# Inequalities Extension 2 Mathematics HSC Australia

Tags: inequality

Knowing:

$$ \sqrt n \leqslant \sqrt {j(n-j+1)} \leqslant {{n+1}\over 2} $$

where the conditions is n and j are positive integers with 1 < j < n

How do I prove for all integers n $$ n \geqslant 1 $$

$$ ({\sqrt n})^n \leqslant n!\leqslant ({{n+1}\over 2})^n $$

Obviously the outside ones you just square by n

However, this being only a 1 mark question, I don't think going through the entire process of induction is efficient, let alone actually works.

Comment: Write $n!$ once as $n (n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1$ and once in the more usual way in the middle term.

Comment: Note: $n! = n(n-1)(n-2).... = n^n +$ some extra terms, and thus is certainly greater than $n^{\frac{n}{2}}$.